# Simulation of ARMA-GARCH in R (garchSim versus ugarchsim)

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, garch

I am trying to simulate an ARMA-GARCH process. From the literature I have consulted, it seems there are two functions for doing this in R: `garchSim` (from "fGarch" package) and `ugarchsim` (from "rugarch" package). I have used both of them but I get different results.

When should I use `garchSim` and when should I use `ugarchsim`?

Comment: I edited the function names because `garchFit` is not for simulation while `rugarch` is not even a function but a package. You may undo the edit if it changes the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid functions for simulating an ARMA-GARCH series. It is not uncommon to find functions in different packages in R that serve the same purpose. However, they differ in some details. `ugarchsim` appears to be a little more flexible as it gives the user a little more control over the simulation process. See the [help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rugarch/docs/ugarchsim) for `ugarchsim` for all the optional parameters.